# Display row of months in SSRS

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2008, reporting

I'm a tad stuck at the moment. I'd like to build a report that displays something like this:

```
Travel cost per city, per month 2015


City | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Total
------------------------------------------
 KC  | 78  | 79  | 84  |  85 |  85 |  411
 STL | 75  | 68  | 73  |  80 |  87 |  383
```

In my actual table, there is a date column and the other columns are titled as city names containing amount spent for said date.

Where I'm getting confused is how I can distribute the data across a row of months, while each city is contained in one column.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem.

What I needed to do was use the DATE function with my date column. This would return a column that would display a number (corresponding to the month). From there, I began creating my report. I put the date column in 'Column groups' and the report ran beautifully.